# Chamada função Javascript apos Carregar pagina

Tags: javascript

Bom dia a todos

Tenho uma função para multiplicar qnt * total, porém ela só carrega depois de clicar no campo `vrunitario`. Gostaria que ao abrir a pagina ela calculasse, não sei onde errei aqui no código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 $("#tbodyCotacao").on("blur keyup load",'input[id^="pqnt"],input[id^="vrunit01"],input[id^="vrunit02"],input[id^="vrunit03"]', function (event) {
  multiplicar($(this).closest("tr"));});

 function multiplicar(row) {
  var vlund01 = row.find('input[id^="vrunit01"]').val();
  //retira separadores de milhar ponto
  vlund01 = vlund01.split(".").join("");
  //substitui separador decimal virgula por ponto
  vlund01=vlund01.replace(",", ".");
  vlund01 = +vlund01;
  var qnd = +row.find('input[id^="pqnt"]').val();
  //total para uso nos calculos
  //2 casas decimais
  var total01 = (vlund01 * qnd).toFixed(2);
  row.find('input[id^="subtotal01"]').val(total01);
  //totalS para uso na apresentação substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
  totalS01=total01.replace(".", ",");
  //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
  row.find('input[id^="subtotal01T"]').val((totalS01).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));
}
```

**MEDIDA PROVISORIA**
Pessoal fiz um medida provisoria, pra aparecer e melhorou mas gostaria que aparecesse no carregamento da pagina.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tbodyCotacao").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover",'input[id^="pqnt"],input[id^="vrunit01"],input[id^="vrunit02"],input[id^="vrunit03"]', function (event) {
  multiplicar($(this).closest("tr"));     
});

function multiplicar(row) {
  var vlund01 = row.find('input[id^="vrunit01"]').val();
  //retira separadores de milhar ponto
  vlund01 = vlund01.split(".").join("");
  //substitui separador decimal virgula por ponto
  vlund01=vlund01.replace(",", ".");
  vlund01 = +vlund01;
  var qnd = +row.find('input[id^="pqnt"]').val();
  //total para uso nos calculos
  //2 casas decimais
  var total01 = (vlund01 * qnd).toFixed(2);
  row.find('input[id^="subtotal01"]').val(total01);
  //totalS para uso na apresentação substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
  totalS01=total01.replace(".", ",");
  //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
  row.find('input[id^="subtotal01T"]').val((totalS01).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));}
```

Comment: No jQuery você pode colocar seu código dentro da função `ready` no `document` que será executado quando o documento for carregado. Exemplo: `$(document).ready(function(){  //seu código  });` ou apenas `$(function(){ //seu código });`

Comment: Não entendi esta parte: `$(this).closest("tr")`. Está tudo dentro de uma `tr`? Pela imagem estou vendo várias linhas e não apenas uma. Ou está tudo dentro de uma `td` numa linha só?

Comment: Isso porque o evento `load` não vai funcionar com div, logo seria necessário criar ele separado e chamar a função `multiplicar(row)`.

Comment: Por que está usando `^=` nos seletores? São vários desses formulários na tela ao mesmo tempo? Esse `vrunitario` é único? Qual o `id` dele? Para fazer o evento `load` funcionar é preciso saber o que enviar na variável `row` da função.

Comment: Teria que fazer `$(window).on("load", function(){ multiplicar(row); });`... o problema é: o que enviar nesse `row` já que não tem o `$(this)` dos outros eventos `blur` e `keyup` que vc criou?

Comment: Lercio - Ja tentei fazer isso nao deu certo.

Comment: Sam - É uma tabela dinamica, insiro e retiro linhas pra mandar salvar no banco. Para inserir funcionou perfeitamente, para exibir que esta dando esse incoveniente. O evento load estava testando pra fazer ele carregar o calculo. Ja fiz a tela pra inserir, essa tela seria pra editar, dai tem que carregar o que esta salvo no banco e ter opção pra inserir o retirar linhas.